# Ruby 2.5.3 to 2.6.0 leads to Policy already configured error

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.6

When I update ruby 2.5.3 to 2.6.0 and try to run RSpec specs then it's throwing `policy already configured` error

The error stack as follows

```rb
An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/example_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

SecureHeaders::Configuration::AlreadyConfiguredError:
  Policy already configured
# /Users/codecpm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/secure_headers-6.1.1/lib/secure_headers/configuration.rb:19:in `default'
# ./config/initializers/secure_header.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

But the server was running fine.

has anybody faced this issue before?

Comment: Hey there! Did you fix this issue? I'm facing the same error right now and it's driving me mad :O